How to calculate dissociation rate of molecular hydrogen ion?
Suppose I have a positive molecular hydrogen ion in a bath of electrons with a temperature $T$. How do I calculate the dissociation rate of the molecule due to electron impact? Should I just use Fermi's Golden Rule with the dipole-electron interaction as the perturbation?
